# How do I remove mentioned users from the command arguments array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I want to be able to remove any user mentions from a command's arguments array.

I've tried following the help provided by the official Discord JS guide on this topic [here](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.md), however the example only works on the mention being in a  specific argument array position.

The aim is to allow users to mention others anywhere within the command arguments (not being limited to those mentions having to be the first, second, last, etc argument) and enact a command aimed at the mentioned user(s).

Comment: Can you please show us some code and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, but the key concept is this: you want to use [`Message.mentions.USERS_PATTERN`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-USERS_PATTERN) to check whether the strings in the arguments' array are mentions; if so, you may want to remove them (or store them in a separate array).

Here is an example:

```
// ASSUMPTIONS: 
// args is an array of arguments (strings)
// message is the message that triggered the command
// Discord = require('discord.js'); -> it's the module

let argsWithoutMentions = args.filter(arg => !Discord.MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN.test(arg));
```

If you need to use  the mentions, you can get them with [`Message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users): please note that they will not be in the order they were sent. If you need them in that order, you can do something like this:

```
let argsWithoutMentions = [],
  mentions = [];

for (let arg of args) {
  if (Discord.MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN.test(arg)) mentions.push(arg);
  else argsWithoutMentions.push(arg);
}

// In order to use those mentions, you'll need to parse them:
// This function is from the guide you previously mentioned (https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.md)
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
  const matches = mention.match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/);
  const id = matches[1];
  return client.users.get(id);
}

let mentionedUsers = [];
for (let mention of mentions) {
  let user = getUserFromMention(mention);
  if (user) mentionedUsers.push(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your first example is exactly what I needed and your assumptions are correct, however, placing it into my code results in the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`. It seems like it doesn't think "arg" is defined.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: [`USERS_PATTERN`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-USERS_PATTERN) is a static property, so it has to be called through the class, not from the instances. I've edited my answer

Comment: There is a special place in the great beyond for people who write same line if and if-else statements.

Comment: @MarcusParsons 